# "Hot Reload Failed to Initialize" permanently

Tags: maui, hot-reload

I am trying to test my .NET MAUI app in **iPhone 14 iOS 16.2 Simulator** under Windows in VS 2022 with Remote Connection to my Mac, which worked previously.

Now, I am permanently getting the message in Visual Studio **"Hot Reload Failed to Initialize"** and I don't know what to do and how to get it working again.

I tried deleting:

- ".vs" directory
- "obj" and "bin" directories
- On Mac: content of directory   /User//Library/Caches

What else can I do to get this running again??

[image]

========= Additional Information regarding instructions from Comment =========

I followed the instructions in the Troubleshooting Link from comments below.

The problem is: It was mentioned that I should set the Linker behavior in the iOS Debug options to **"Don't Link"**. When I do this, I get the following error:

[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot update XCode on the build system to try it out. So, it seems like I have to stick to Debug Option **"Link Framework SDKs Only"**. But when I do this, I always get **"XAML Hot Reload Failed to Initialize"** and no Live-Preview or Hot Reload action can be performed.

Other thatn that, I also checked my settings, which look like in the Troubleshooting link:

[image]

Are there other things I could try?

Comment: May I know what is your VS version and Xcode version? Have you tried to walk through the [troublehooting docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/hot-reload?tabs=vswin#troubleshooting)?

Comment: I use VS 2022 on Windows and XCode 14.2  -  in the meantime I could get it going again with a fresh project and deleting all file/folders in /Users/myUser/Library/Cache   But even that did not help in the beginning

Comment: It is VS 17.6.4

Comment: It it's still not working, it's suggested to report Visual Studio tooling issues is via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see [How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-201).

Comment: Now it is working again, but still has this message in VS Status Bar, but at least it is working. I also deleted caches directory on the Mac which is used to compile the app, which probably helped the most ;)

Comment: Well, it’s not solved completely as there are some downsides combined with that, as the XAML Live View which is not working. Don’t know if this is iPhone Simulator related, but would definitely be worth it to change in XAML and see without timeconsuming recompile, load of emulator etc.  Costs a lot of time

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT - Please see updates in my original Post

Comment: It's suggested to report Visual Studio tooling issues is via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see [How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-201)